# Is there a way to get the version of a dependency from within build.gradle?

Tags: gradle, build, dependencies, build.gradle, gradlew

Here's my issue, I'm pulling latest.release based on the region that the project is in:

```
if (System.getenv()["namespace"].contains("dev")) {
       compile("com.foo.bar.dev:library:latest.release")
   } else if (System.getenv()["namespace"].contains("test")) {
       compile("com.foo.bar.test:library:latest.release")
   } else {
       compile("com.foo.bar.other:library:latest.release")
   }
```

Is there a way to resolve this dependency for a line later on that specifically wants to grab the jar version?

```
def zipFile = file("build/libs/foobar/library-${projectVersion}.jar")
```

Thanks for any assistance, the best I've found is dependencyInsight from the command line but I specifically need this automated in a task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just want to path of the resolved JAR. If I understood correctly, then you can resolve the configuration and filter the dependency you want. For example, using `commons-lang3`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.11")
}

val commonsLang3Jar = configurations.compileClasspath.get().filter { it.name.startsWith("commons-lang3") }.singleFile

println(commonsLang3Jar.absolutePath)
```

This results in the following line being printed:

```
~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.11/68e9a6adf7cf8eb7e9d31bbc554c7c75eeaac568/commons-lang3-3.11.jar
```

Comment: That should be enough to get me started, thanks a ton!